# 'View More' button in Angular 6 will open all paragraphs instead of just the one

Tags: angular, typescript

On my project, I have a summary section. If the text length is more than 30 characters, there will be a 'view more' button that will show the full paragraphs. The more problem is that when there is more than one 'view more' button, all paragraphs will be expanded instead of just the one.

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

my HTML:

```
<td class="description">
    <div *ngIf="content.description.length > 30 && expanded == false">
        {{content.description.substring(0,30)}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="expanded == true">{{content.description}}</div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm" *ngIf="content.description.length > 30"
            (click)="this.expanded = !this.expanded;">{{expanded?'Less':'View More'}}</button>
    </div>
 </td>
```

my .ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-test",
  templateUrl: "./test.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./test.component.css"],
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  expanded: boolean = false;
}
```

How can I target only one paragraph and ensure the others will not?

Comment: Use one component per paragraph. Each component will have its own `expanded` property. Or, if you really want to stick with a single component, use one expended property per paragraph (i.e. make expanded a property of `content`, not a property of the component)

Answer (score 1):

the variable `expanded` is used for both paragraphs which is your problem.

If you wrap the functionality in a component the expanded property will be local to each component instance, which will make it work.

```
paragraph 1
  expanded = false

paragraph 2
  expanded = true
```

````
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hide-me',
  template: `
    <button (click)="toggle()">Show/Hide</button>
    <div *ngIf="expanded">{{text}}</div>
  `
})
export class HideMeComponent {
  @Input()
  text: string;

  expanded = false

  toggle() {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }
}

```

usage

```
<app-hide-me [text]="todo.message"></app-hide-me>
```
````

Comment: do you have a short example for this?

Comment: @mhfour Added an example component for you

Comment: i've made an edit to my post. i don't really see any difference between what i have and what you have suggested

Comment: I thought you might have an *ngFor somewhere up the stack, and you where not using a component to wrap the functionality, which would mean that you had one global expanded variable. Make sure each instance of the paragraph has it's own component that will mean that you have one variable per paragraph.

Comment: Here's a little example with 2 possible ways to solve your issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3setf One is simply using different component instances to have each `expand` only apply to one instance, the other approach (if you want all your expandable content within the same component) is to use template variable on each one of them. 
Let me know if that helps a bit :)